# 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: microsoft-access, database, sql-server

this error is very common but in my case, is very strange why is being produced.

I have developed a 64 bits application that uses an Access database. To be able to run it, I installed 64 bits version of AcessDatabaseEngine.

On the other hand, I have SQL Server Management Studio 17.2, 64 bits also, but, when I try to import an xlsx file with the Import Wizard, it shows the error "'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine".

If I uninstall 64 bits of AcessDatabaseEngine and install 32 bits version, SQL Server Management Studio works, but my application stops working.

The most curious thing, is that this worked before. I could use both SQL Server Management Studio and my application at the same time. Suddenly, SSMS stopped working.

Other fact is: even when I installed 64 bits version of SSMS, it was actually installed in "Program Files (x86)". I think this is the cause, so the question is, how can I solve this problem without the need to uninstall and install Access Engine components every time I use one application or the other?

Best regards,

Jaime

Comment: I assume you're downloading from here but try a fresh download copy and see what happens. I recall things like this in the past vaguely where I had to uninstall the correlated SQL components and then reboot, install SSMS and then the ACE drivers. Did you do an upgrade install over existing SSMS initially? Just throwing around some ideas in case you've not already tried. It may be an SSMS 2017 bug that's unknown but sometimes uninstall and then re-installing in spec order helps. Just a quick idea without research.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms is where I was talking about for downloading the latest package of SSMS but check for the latest ACE Access drivers too.